# AirPrint and Apple Configurator

Tags: ipad, airprint, apple-configurator

I have a small office setup where I control certain functionality of a set of iPads. One of the things I need to do is to be able to allow a set of iPads to AirPrint, while keeping others from doing the same. Is there a way through either the Apple Configurator, or the iPhone Configuration Utility, to disable AirPrint by device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to implement [Printopia Pro](http://www.printopiapro.com), which incorporates user groups. This has the effect of locking down the printers except for the users who need access. If you own Printopia, you can get $20 off on an upgrade to Pro. If you need permission-based printing like I do, I'd recommend doing so.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you are looking for but why don't you set a password.
Look here: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11450?viewlocale=en_US.
You can share a printer and specify a user so who tries to print must enter a username and a password.

Comment: The printer is networked, not connected to a Mac or PC. I'd consider printing and requiring a password to do so, but the printer firmware doesn't have a facility to incorporate one (other than password protecting against unwanted changes).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hackey but if your router supports it, you can whitelist only the traffic from the permitted MAC addresses to the printer.  The printer would probably still show up in the AirPrint menu, but wouldn't actually be usable by those blacklisted.

Comment: I use an Airport Extreme, which permits whitelisting to the extent that I can filter MAC addresses that connect to the network, but as far as filtering them based upon accessing the printer, I would have to look at it in more detail. That's a thought though.